# PowerBIClient GenerateToken Returns NotFound

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerbi, webforms

My company is moving to Power BI and I am needing to pull reports from it in our web portal where the development started in 2006 and uses web forms. The framework version is 4.7. I work at a large company and cannot easily change security settings on PowerBI so I am hoping that if someone recognizes that this is caused by a setting, they will let me know what it is that I need to ask for. When running the code below, I get Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'. Since most of the users will not be on the domain when they are using the web portal, I need to pull the reports without the Azure AD login. I can get the report if I use code that uses ClaimsPrincipal.

```
public void EmbedReport()
        {
            string clientId = "1111111111111111111111111111111111";
            string clientSecret = "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222";
            string tenantId = "333333333333333333333333333333333333333";
            string workspaceId = "444444444444444444444444444444444444444";
            string reportId = "555555555555555555555555555555555555555"; 

            var accessToken = GetAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId);
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);

            using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com"), tokenCredentials))
            {
                //var embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(workspaceId, reportId, new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view"));
                var embedTokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequest(TokenAccessLevel.View);
                
                //The error happens on the line below, Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
                var embedTokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateToken(new Guid(workspaceId), new Guid(reportId), embedTokenRequest);    

            }
        }

private string GetAccessToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantId)
        {
            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                .Build();

            var scopes = new[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" };
            var result = confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I decided to go a little different route. The answer is in the repository, https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master And then follow the example that is in .NET Framework/Embed for your customers project.